# jQuery Function Issue with Dynamic Created HTML

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic

I'm having hard time understanding why this doesn't work.

When I create an HTML file with additional copies populated it works fine.
When I run the same and create the new copies using the script (HTML is exactly the same) it just doesn't work on newly created copies/forms.

If you check the example below and click "add more" on top it will create another copy of the form. When you click on presets or calculate button it just doesn't work on new created forms.

http://jsfiddle.net/4sM8p/2/

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove multiple `document.ready(function()` functions. Use only one.

Use event delegation.

[More info here.](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Change:

```
$(".doit").click(function(){...
$(".usingle").click(function(){...
$(".uone").click(function(){...
$(".asingle").click(function(){...
$(".udouble").click(function(){...
$(".adouble").click(function(){...
```

to:

```
$("#quotecalc").on("click",".doit",function(){...
$("#quotecalc").on("click",".usingle",function(){...
$("#quotecalc").on("click",".uone",function(){...
$("#quotecalc").on("click",".asingle",function(){...
$("#quotecalc").on("click",".udouble",function(){...
$("#quotecalc").on("click",".adouble",function(){...
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/4sM8p/3/)